# Apex Trigger to Insert Opportunity Owner on Custom Task Field

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm not the best at writing Apex code. I really just need an Apex trigger to insert the Opportunity Owner NAME into a custom Task field named OPP OWNER. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edited to add code and error:

This is what I currently have:

```
trigger setOpportunityOwner on Task (before insert, before update) { 
    MAP<Id, Task> taskmap = [Select Owner.UserName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]; 
    for(Task o: Trigger.new) { 
         o.Opp_Owner__c = taskmap.get(o.id).owner.UserName;
    }
}
```

but I keep receiving this error: **Invalid bind expression type of Task for Id field of SObject Opportunity**

Comment: This is where you would start: [Apex Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm). Then you could work your way through this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro). Then to improve your trigger coding standards, go here: [Apex Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices). If you stuck/blocked with some sort of error/issue, post it here. People here are really amazing, and happy to help out peer developers.

Comment: Arnold, 

This is what I currently have:

`trigger setOpportunityOwner on Task (before insert, before update) 
  {
            MAP<Id, Task> taskmap = [Select Owner.UserName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];
            for(Task o: Trigger.new)
            {
                o.Opp_Owner__c = taskmap.get(o.id).owner.UserName;
            }
        }`

but I keep receiving this error: **Invalid bind expression type of Task for Id field of SObject Opportunity**

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/279574/edit) your post by adding what you have tried so far. Comments are not a good place to include code-snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `trigger setOpportunityOwner on Task (before insert, before update) {
>     MAP<Id, Task> taskmap = [Select Owner.UserName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];
>     for(Task o: Trigger.new) {
>       o.Opp_Owner__c = taskmap.get(o.id).owner.UserName;
>     }
>   }`

The first issue with your code is that you're taking an Opportunity query and assigning it to a Map, and one for Id to Task for that matter. You will need to change it to a Map for Id to Opportunity. And you can't assign the query directly to it, it will need to be passed into a new Map constructor first like such:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([Select Owner.UserName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]);
```

That just solves the first problem. The other issue you have is that you haven't identified the connection between Opportunities and Task. If your tasks are related to the Opportunity through the WhatId field, then you need to check first that the WhatId belongs to an Opportunity (Opportunity Ids have a prefix of 006), and then query for the Opportunites only in that case. If it is a custom lookup that connects the Tasks to the Opportunities, then you can just use that Id field to query for the Opportunities and then get the Owner names from there. Assuming you are using the WhatId field to relate the Opportunity, here is how you would the get Owner names:

```
trigger setOpportunityOwner on Task (before insert, before update) {
  Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
  for ( Task newTask : Trigger.new ) {
    if ( newTask.WhatId != null && newTask.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType ) {
      oppIds.add( newTask.WhatId );
    }
  }
  Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([Select Owner.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]);
  for(Task newTask: Trigger.new) {
    if ( oppMap.containsKey( newTask.WhatId ) ) {
      newTask.Opp_Owner__c = oppMap.get( newTask.WhatId ).Owner.Name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Roti,Thank you so so so much! That's exactly what I needed. I don't want to bug you more, but could you please point me in the right direction to get code coverage on this?

Comment: Certainly! For help with test classes, you can use the trailhead here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing
In general, what you will want to do for this test (do not use SeeAllData=true) is create an Opportunity and insert it, then create a Task, assign the Opportunity's Id as the Task's WhatId and insert that. Then query the Task and the Opportunity and check that the Task's Opp_Owner__c == the Opportunity's Owner.Name with an assert statement. Hope that helps.

Comment: `String.valueOf( newTask.WhatId ).startsWith( '006' )` should be written as `newTask.WhatId.getSobjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType`

Comment: @cropredy - that is indeed the correct way. But I always forget the correct way to check Id SObject type (whether it was through the schema or global describe or what), so I just use the hacky String method. It's a bad habit that I need to fix. I'll revise my answer so as to not recommend the bad habit to others. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: That's what we're here for.  To help the Community